# Can't connect my monitor with DVI

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, vga, dvi

My monitor has always been connected with VGA. I wanted to connect it with a DVI cable. I turned off the computer, connected the DVI and turn on the computer.

I received nothing on the screen, nothing changed and I heard a long "*bip*" from the PC. This sound lasted 3 seconds, then stopped. When it stopped, I turned off the computer and reconnect with the old VGA cable.

My PC:

- Motherboard : MSI-970A-G46
- Processor : AMD FX-6300 Black Edition
- Graphics : Sapphire Radeon R9 270X Dual-X OC
- Windows 10
- Monitor : Asus VE247H 24".

All the drivers are installed and updated.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do ensure that you have the right kind of DVI cable. There are more than one type of connection:

[image]

If you do have the right cable for the job, then try it with another computer or monitor to try and see if either is the problem.

I did look at your video card and it appears you have two different DVI plug types:

[image]

I also looked up your monitor:

[image]

So your video card uses DVI-I and DVI-D. Your monitor supports DVI-D. Make sure your cable is DVI-D and then make sure you plug it into the DVI-D port of your video card.

Comment: My cable is a DVI-D single link according to your picture. I tried to connect the cable on the DVI-I graphic card output. Is it important that I have a single link cable? Did it should work if I connect my DVI-D single link cable on the DVI-I dual link graphic card output? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TotomInc Try plugging a DVI-D (single link) cable from the DVI-D port on your video card to the DVI-D port on your monitor.

Comment: It doesn't works, still the same problem, PC is giving me "*bips*". But it's more like "*biiiiiip bip bip*" so translate this by a long bip and 2 short bips. :) Maybe I should go on HDMI?

Comment: Maybe it can be the cause that I got a single link? Because monitor and graphic card are both DVI-D dual link. I will be back in some hours, thanks for your help!

Comment: @TotomInc Most definitely that can be the case. Make sure your cable is dual link too. If this does help, please mark this as a solution.

Comment: I will try with an HDMI cable ASAP. Thanks for your help!